# hazelcast transaction notification

Tags: transactions, notifications, hazelcast

Looking at latest Hazelcast doc,

Suppose there is a Hazelcast map and set, and we perform a transaction that update both of them. Now, consider the problem that a listener need to perform some actions based on a consistent view of both the map and the set, but only need to do it once when a transaction happens.

Is there a good way to implement such callback mechanism for hazelcast transactions? Is there inherent support for this or this is something that need to be done at the client side?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are transaction listeners.  But, I think for your `transaction` example `topics` are the mechanism you want.

Setup topic listener

```
// setup on client 2
// define...
//     class Topic1Event ...
//     class Topic1Listener implements MessageListener<Topic1Event> ...
HazelcastInstance hc2;
hc2.getTopic("topic1").addMessageListener(new Topic1Listener)
```

Then a transaction

```
// client 1
HazelcastInstance hc1;
TransactionContext tc1= hc1.newTransactionContext
tc1.beginTransaction
tc1.getMap("map1").set("key1", "value1")
tc1.getSet("set1").add("value2")
tc1.commitTransaction
// TransactionContext doesn't have getTopic
hc1.getTopic("topic1").publish(new Topic1Event)
```

! pseudo code above -- does not compile !

So sure, you can do it with listeners on the `map` or `set` but that probably obscures your intentions.  For example later your code might evolve to have more collections and remove the one you attached your listener to.  Then you've got a bug.

If you have a topic, now you can even use your *Topic1Event* to pass a transaction sequence number or some other meta info.

**EDITED**: `TransactionContext` doesn't have `getTopic`